# Delete rows from a left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, sql-delete

I want to join two tables and delete from them.

table1:

```
|ID| DATA|
```

table2:

```
|ID | ID_TAB1|
```

The query looks like this:

```
delete from table2 
using table2 as t2 left join table1 as t1 
on t2.ID_TAB1=t1.ID 
where t1.DATA='xxx';
```

The problem is that there is a third table:

table3:

```
|ID|ID_TAB2|
```

When I run my statement it fails saying

> Update or deleting on table table2 violates foreign key contraint on table table3

I'm sure there are no data in the table3 connected to rows with `t1.DATA='xxx'` so why is there this error? Isn't my query correct?

Comment: first try to remove foreign key constraint and run delete statement after

Comment: But I need the constraint there. Also I have a big db full of data, I don't want to rebuild it now.

Comment: When I delete just a single row without the join, it works and the constraint is not a problem.

Comment: The error makes it sound like perhaps the third table is pointing to one or more records which are being deleted.  Are you certain this is not the case?

Comment: Yes, I'm certain. There are no records in the third table where this is true t1.DATA='xxx'

Comment: That LEFT JOIN executes as a regular inner join, since you have that t1 condition in the WHERE clause. Move to ON to get true left join!

Comment: @jarlh And how would that look like? I wanted to join the tables based on one common attribute (id/id_tab1) and then delete the rows where the condition is true.

Comment: Perhaps you want an inner join?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query:

```
delete from table2 
using table2 as t2 left join table1 as t1 
on t2.ID_TAB1=t1.ID 
where t1.DATA='xxx';
```

Is actually deleting all rows from `table2` (or none if there is no match in the `where`.  You have no connection between `t2` and `table2`, so that is essentially a cross join.

As explained (deep down) in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/sql-delete.html):

> Do not repeat the target table in the using_list, unless you wish to set up a self-join.

Presumably, deleting all the rows is causing the problem with the third table.  Note that the rows that you really do want to delete could also be causing the problem.  In that case, you need to handle the errors using some sort of cascading logic.

You can express this using a `using` clause and removing the `join`:

```
delete from table2 t2
    using table1 t1 
    where t2.ID_TAB1 = t1.ID  and
          t1.DATA = 'xxx';
```

Or, just use `exists` in the `where` clause:

```
delete from table2 t2
    where exists (select 1
                  from table1 t1
                  where t1.id = t2.id_tab1 and t1.data = 'xxx'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant:

```
delete from table2 
 using table1
where  table2.ID_TAB1=table1.ID 
  and  table1.DATA='xxx';
```

How does it differ from your query:

- it does not reintroduce a second, independant instance of `table2`. Otherwise the query would delete all rows from `table2`.
- the `left` qualification for the join is misused. The point of a left join is to include rows from `table2` that has no corresponding `table1.id` with the missing `table1` columns set to NULL. But the condition `t1.DATA='xxx'` contradicts this.